# Delphi soap (httprio) ignore certificate validation

Tags: web-services, delphi, ssl, soap

i have a https soap and i want ignore the certificate validation. I have done that with `OnBeforePost` event into `THTTPRIO.HTTPWebNode`:

```
procedure TMySOAP.OnBeforePost(const HTTPReqResp: THTTPReqResp; Data: Pointer);
var
  aFlagsSize: DWord;
  aFlags:     DWord;
begin
  aFlagsSize := SizeOf(aFlags);

  // get security flags
  if InternetQueryOption(Data, INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS, @aFlags, aFlagsSize) then
  begin
      // add all flag for ignore validation
      aFlags := aFlags or
       SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA or
       SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_REVOCATION or
       SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID or
       SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID or
       SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_WRONG_USAGE;

      // set the new flags
      InternetSetOption(Data, INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS, @aFlags, aFlagsSize)
  end;
end;
```

it works.. but i have a second problem. My clients are behind a company firewall without internet and each request to the soap loses 15 seconds because Windows try to validate the certificate path throug internet and this operation has a default timeout of 15 seconds (see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771429(v=ws.11).aspx).

There is any flag or snippet for set at runtime, a custom retrieval timeout settings?

Answer (score 0):

**THTTPRIO.HTTPWebNode** has:

```
property  ConnectTimeout: Integer;
property  SendTimeout: Integer; 
property  ReceiveTimeout: Integer;
```

All of them are in milliseconds.

```
RIO := THTTPRIO.Create(nil);
RIO.HTTPWebNode.ReceiveTimeout := 20000; //Wait just 20 secs
```

Comment: But he is asking for a  custom retrieval timeout settings also.